# pyautogui stops after a few hours in VNC Desktop

Tags: python, pyautogui, vnc

I have a VNC Desktop (using realvnc) with a pyautogui script. The script works for a few hours, the pyautogui raises an error because it doesn't have access to the display anymore (it says the cursor was forcefully placed to 0x0).

What can I change in the VNC settings so that the display is kept alive no matter what ? The VNC server runs on Raspbian, a Debian fork.